# How to generate .elf by using Cmake tool

Tags: embedded, elf, cmake-gui

I am using CMake tool for windows, I am able to generate.exe but I don't know how we can generate .elf.

[image]

[image]

I tried to set the toolchain in main CMakeLists.txt and output file to .elf extension in subdirectory CMakelists.txt.  check the image for more information.

Comment: Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Then come back and [edit] your question, presenting your CMake file and source as code. Additionally, you might want to do the expected research (starting at [CMake's documentation on cross compiling](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/book/mastering-cmake/chapter/Cross%20Compiling%20With%20CMake.html)) and refine your question.

Comment: Do not post _pictures_ of _text_.  Post the plain text.  Not sure why that should need saying, but apparently it does - frequently.  So you are not alone.

Comment: The important part is possibly the my_toolchain.cmake file you omitted.

Comment: @Clifford I assume he omitted it because he doesn't know about it, leaving him to  (poorly) ask this question about how to cross compile.